# BigDecimal Hibernate with precision and scale or another type (performance)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Im creating a new app which stores amoung others some price informations.

On one hand i found a lot articles about using BigDecimal should be preferred for mathematic operations but on other hand there also a lot of articles which state that the performance of BigDecimal can be not ideal compared to other types like Double, Float, ...

In my certain case i know that the prices i will store will have never more digits than ####.##. There will be, if any, very few calculations but a lot of sorting. What would be the best datatype to use now?
First i was thinking i could use a Float. Then i found out that i can configure a BigDecimal in Hibernate with the help of precision and scale. My underlying database will be a postgresql.

Does anybody have a recommendation which type to use for my case or it depends on various of uses case which type to prefer?
As im expecting to have more than one million records later im a bit scared that i could have a performance problem if i choose the wrong type from the beginning.

Comment: the datatype does not effect the how fast the database stores the values. only if you do calculations with them in your VM it affects the performance. i have a table with waay to many entries for Aqua Data Studio to hold in 1 select and i map the price values to an BigDecimal in my java program. There is no performance gain if i would change it to double or float, since my database is not affected by it. in MSSql Server, `BigDecimal` is stored as datatype `Number`

Comment: it really depends on what you want to do with the values. if its some heavy calculation and precision is **not** required, you can go with float or double. if precision is a must, go with big decimal

Comment: Added it just to my question. Calculations will be very rare but i need to do a lot of sortings.

Comment: what kind of sorting? maybe you can let the database do the sorting for you. this would probably increase the overall performance a bit. i think in your case using a BigDecimal is fine. and even if you want to try double/float, the conversion shouldn't be too hard, but better save the code with bigDecimal somewhere before you move to double